# Prove that a linear map is continuous if and only if it is continuous at 0.

Tags: real-analysis

Let L : $\mathbb{R}^2$ →  $\mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear map. Prove that L is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if L is continuous at (0,0).

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to start, but there is one way where its straightforward. That is when L continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ then it is continuous at (0, 0)

Comment: It's a weird problem, since linear maps between finite dimensional spaces are always continuous.

Comment: But how to prove that L is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ if it is continuous at (0, 0)? @SamM

Comment: reopen: A linear functional is a linear map, but not all linear maps are linear functionals.

Comment: then how I prove L continuous if it is cont at 0?? @mvw

Comment: Let us assume the limit at $0$ exists, then:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} f(r_0 + h) =
\lim_{h \to 0} (f(r_0) + f(h)) =
f(r_0) + \lim_{h \to 0} f(h) =
f(r_0) + f(0) =
f(r_0) + 0 =
f(r_0)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Implication is obvious. Conversely, suppose $L$ continuous at $0$.

$$|L(a+h)-L(a)|=|L(h)|\underset{h\to 0}{\overset{L\ continuous\ at\ 0}{\longrightarrow} }0$$
what prove the claim.